# RegionFunction with a parametric curve

Tags: plotting

I would like to produce contour and density plots for a known function of x and y for x>=0 and y>=0. The function has a singularity curve in the x-y plane and I only want to evaluate the function inside that curve.  However, the curve is known only parametrically so it is not clear to me how to use RegionFunction. Suggestions?

Comment: Please give an example about such function.

Comment: So the singularity curve is a simple, closed loop? (Inferred from "inside.")

Comment: Good questions.  My contour function and singularity curve are really ugly and I don't see how I can include them.  However, the shape of the curve is relatively simple - sort of a quarter of a circle in the first quadrant of the x-y plane with the center at  {0,0}.  Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming examplary function(singularity)

```
f[x_]:= ((3/4 - x/2)/(1/2 + x))  
reg = ImplicitRegion[x >= 0 && y >= 0 && y <= f[x], {x, y}]
RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image]

`ContourPlot[ ... , Element[{x,y},reg]]` restricts your plots to the region `reg`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?:

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
  ParametricPlot[{Exp[Cos[t]], Log[2 + Sin[t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[2 x y], {x, y} \[Element] reg]
```

[image]

Alternative:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[2 x y],
 {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]]
 ]
```

Comment: The alternative technique looks promising.  My curve isn't closed - it is sort of a quarter of a circle in the first quadrant of the x-y plane.  So I need to go from  t = 0  to  t=Pi/2.  But that doesn't seem to work with your technique (which does work for  t = 0 to 2Pi),  Also is there any way to use ParametricRegion instead of BoundaryDiscreteGraphics?  I attempted this but ended up with a lot of error messages involving Throw[$Failed].

Comment: @user26718 To get help with code that doesn't work, it's best to post the code. Diagnosing problems blind is usually fruitless, and no one is likely to try to help you. --- This works for me in the above code, I think, though it's still running 6-7 hours later: `reg = ParametricRegion[{s (Exp[Cos[t]] - 1),  s Log[1 + Sin[t]/2]}, {{s, 0, 2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}}]`. Discretizing the region (e.g. `DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{0, 5}, {0, 2}}]` will greatly speed things up usually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the question is how to construct a region by some curves.(Thanks @Michael E2 provide a function and an example).

Here is one way.

```
f[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]}; 
reg = 
 ParametricRegion[{0, 0} + s*f[t], {{t, 0, π/2}, {s, 0, 1}}];
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Cos[2 x y], {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  Just what I need.   Thank you so much.